# cast child class into parent class

Tags: oop, class, inheritance, casting

this is just a sample code

```
 class parent{ //abstact class
        //pure virtual function
        virtual fun=0;
    }
    class child : parent{
        fun;
    }
    main()
    {
           //what should i do here,so i can add parent in vector
        attach(child);
    }
    void attach(parent* p){
        vector.push_back(p); //want to add reference of parent into vecotr
    }
```

and i want to cast child into parent but not able 
to do please any one help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The child instance has the **type** parent (and child). If you have an instance of child, there is no extra instance of parent lying around. You can use a child instance wherever a parent instance is required. There is no need to cast.

Comment: Thank you very much because of little mistake i got error but your answer solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class cast excetion :
 Occurs when u try to cast a parent class into child class.
 Reason: the parent class has not everything that a child class has, on the other hand a       child has everything that a parent has so you can cast a child into parent.
         In other words, the instance that you want to downcast  must be an instance of the class that to which you are downcasting.
```