# casting between two derived classes

Tags: c++, class, casting

is it legal to cast between pointers on classes that have common ancestor? Does the compiler notice such hierarchy and makes sure its safe (call 1) ? 
Or does the user have to go through the hierarchy manually for it to be always safe (call 2) ?

say we have

```
class A{};
class B:A{};
class C:A
{ 
public:
 int SomeFunc(){return 3;}
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B* b = (B*)((A*)new C()); // this is done manually, i believe it is safe

  ((C*)b)->SomeFunc(); // is this safe? this is the cast in question

  return ((C*)((A*)b))->SomeFunc(); // this is done manually, i believe it is safe
}
```

edit: Made this code compilable and runnable

edit2: Added more comments

Comment: You can only type cast it to parent class first, and then to other class, which you seem to have got in the 3rd line. the second line is not safe. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979661/cast-child-class-into-parent-class)

Comment: Remove the C-style `(B*)` cast on the first line and try compiling again. That should tell you something. The rest of the casting madness is just that. Stop it.

Comment: I think that my question is a bit different than the one you linked  to.  So the cast  B->C is illegal but cast  B->A->C is legal, and the compiler wont make that one step automatically?

Comment: B and C are not related. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: Don't use C casts. Use dynamic_cast, observe the result and learn what it means.

Comment: B and C are related through A and the second "manual" cast is fully legal as far as i know. My question was if the standard guarantees for the first cast to be safe too

Comment: Neither cast is safe. Just because it lets you compile it, doesn't mean it's safe. This is C++ not Java!

Comment: Care to explain why the manual cast is not safe? It consists of two parent-child casts

Comment: The cast from A to C is only safe if A actually points to an object of type C (or derived from it). B is not.

Comment: Ok I see what you did there. You create object C and immediately cast to B. I no longer know if this is safe.

Comment: I edited the question to draw attention to the key detail.

Comment: I edited the question to make it compilable and runnable - i think its fully legal except the first call to SomeFunc() - of which im not sure

Comment: it doesn't address the use of C style casts and bad coding style. The fact that a C looks like a B doesn't mean it's a good idea to cast it to a B. One of them might change and then this code will crash horribly.

Comment: You are wrong, without the line in question it will never crash, whatever is in those classes. My question is whether it will ever crash with that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B* b = (B*)((A*)new C()); // this is done manually, i believe it is safe
```

This is **not** safe.
Casts of the form `(T)` *expr* are, roughly speaking, converted into either `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast`. [expr.cast]/4:

> The conversions performed by
>
> - a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
> - a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
> - a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
> - a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10), or
> - a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
>
> can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.
>   **The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply** […]
>  If a
>   conversion can be interpreted in more than one of the ways listed
>   above, the interpretation that appears first in the list is used, even
>   if a cast resulting from that interpretation is ill-formed.

You can ignore `const_cast` here as no qualification conversions are done in your code.
`static_cast` suffices in both casts, the first one, `(A*)`, and the second one, `(B*)`.
The first one is just fine. Upcasting is never an issue.
The second one induces undefined behavior. [expr.static.cast]/11:

> A prvalue of type “pointer to *cv1* `B`,” where `B` is a class type,
>   can be converted to a prvalue of type “pointer to *cv2* `D`”, where
>   `D` is a class derived (Clause 10) from `B`, if a valid standard
>   conversion from “pointer to `D`” to “pointer to `B`” exists (4.10),
>   *cv2* is the same cv-qualification as, or greater cv-qualification than, *cv1*, and `B` is neither a virtual base class of `D` nor a base
>   class of a virtual base class of `D`. […] **If the prvalue of type
>   “pointer to cv1 B” points to a `B` that is actually a subobject of an
>   object of type `D`, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing
>   object of type `D`. Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined.**

Note also that just because the `static_cast` triggers UB that doesn't mean it isn't selected (and replaced by `reinterpret_cast`).

The second and third casts base on the first one (which causes undefined behavior), thus talking about their validity is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really really know what your doing, don't do that.

The casts are legal, but using them on anything but the correct class results in undefined behaviour, any use of `b` without further casts results in UB, which might work, do nothing or start WWIII.

The casts simply tells the compiler that is should consider the variable to be of another type (unless it is multiple inheritance), but as soon as the cast variable is used it must actual be legal to use it in the way the code does, using B's function table is no good if the object is a C or vice versa. As this is undefined behaviour the compiler might emit whatever code it feels is right.

Example

```
class AA { };
class BB { };
class CC : public AA, public BB { };
int main () {
    CC cc; // address is 0x22aa6f
    BB* bb = &cc; // bb now is 0x22aa6f
    cout << &cc << "," << bb << "\n";

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Gives

> 0x22aa6f,0x22aa6f

Example with multiple inheritance

```
class AX{ int a = 1; };
class BX{ int b = 2; };
class CX:AX,BX {
public:
 int c = 3;
 int SomeFunc(){cout << "SomeFunc " << c << " "; return c;}
};

int cast() {
  CX* c;
  BX* b = (BX*)((AX*)(c = new CX())); // this is done manually, i believe it is safe
  cout << "c=" << c << ", b=" << b << ", cx=" << ((CX*)b) << ", ca=" << ((CX*)((AX*)b)) << endl;
  ((CX*)b)->SomeFunc(); // is this safe? this is the cast in question

  return ((CX*)((AX*)b))->SomeFunc(); // this is done manually, i believe it is safe
}

int main () {
    return cast();
}
```

output

> c=0x60003ac70, b=0x60003ac70, cx=0x60003ac6c, ca=0x60003ac70
>   SomeFunc 2 SomeFunc 3

- c is the real address of the `new`
- b is the cast to AX first which is c then to BX (which doesn't make any sense for AX) but b is just set to the same address as c
- cx is b reinterpreted as CX, multi-inheritance kicks in and really change the address as if b was the 2nd class in the inheritance.
- ca is the correct reinterpretation of b through AX and then CX.

The 2 calls to SomeFunc works despite the wrong address

- the function call is found through the current type which is CX due to the last cast.
- the wrong addresses are passed as `this` pointer
- because `this` is not used it works, so I had to add some use.
- now we have entered undefined behaviour due to the cast (BX*)((AX*)c which makes the cast (CX*)b do the wrong thing.

To check if it is safe you need to use dynamic_cast.

```
int main() {
  A* AP = new C();
  C* CP = dynamic_cast<C*>(A);
  if (CP != nullptr)
    CP->SomeFunc();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;   
}
```

Comment: Sorry but this is just some advice, it doesnt answer the question

Comment: Even the line in question is legal cast?

Comment: So if cast A->B adds 6 to pointer value and cast A->C adds 0 to pointer value then B->C will subtract 6 from pointer value? I could use some reference to that answer.

Comment: just inherit from two classes and then cast on the second one, the pointer must stay valid so it has to point on the beginning of the second inherited class which cannot occupy the same space as the first inherited class

Comment: And now put member variable in both AA and BB; And then maybe you can upvote my question so someone notices it and answers

Comment: cleaned up the comments, and added a example with multiple inheritance (which was not your question).

Answer (score 1):

To check whether a cast is meaningful or not just use dynamic_cast. dynamic_cast will cast properly if cast is safe OR returns NULL (in case of pointers, for references it throws bad_cast exception ) if its not able to cast to target type.

For your question just think about whether this cast is meaningful. You are casting B class to C where these classes have no knowledge of each other. **So, surely this cast would fail.**

You are doing:-

```
B* b = (B*)(new C());
```

This would fail(means won't even compile ) if given to dynamic_cast since classes involved are not polymorphic. Even if you make class B polymorphic cast would fail. Leave further casting.

One more thing you can cross cast using dynamic_cast safely assuming classes are polymorphic and cast is safe. For e.g:-

```
class A;
Class B;
Class C : public A, public B

A *a = new C;
```

You can cast this to sibling:-

```
B *b = dynamic_cast<B*> (a);
```

Comment: Well as i demonstrated in the code - that cast B->C is entirely possible when done as B->A->C, so your statement that it would fail  carries little proof - moreso when the code runs.

Comment: that it compiles and runs doesn't mean it's sensible, a good habit to get into, safe or maintainable.

Comment: @user1316208 To get correct definition of working just use dynamic_cast instead of static_cast you have done.

Comment: @ravi I dont want to use other casts- thats like telling someone whos asking how to ride bike to go drive a car instead

Comment: @user1316208 No, it's more like telling someone to wear a helmet when they are asking how to ride a bike. Safety first.

Answer (score 0):

Your casts are both legal and correct but very dangerous. You should use reinterpret_cast<> to tag them in your code.
You can always cast any address of any type `A` to any other address of any type `B` and get your first address back. This is essentially what you've done:

```
A *pa = &some_a;
B *pb = reinterpret_cast<B *>(pa);
pa = reinterpret_cast<A *>(pb);
```

and then dereference `pa`. This example works but it is so easy to make a mistake...